# Prettify booktabs table with subheadings/categories

Tags: tables, booktabs

I basically want to list attribute names and a attribute description in a table. The attributes belong to a certain category. The idea is to list all attributes in one table to avoid creating multiple tables for each category. At the moment I am simply subdividing the table by using midrules for each category. The result looks ok, but I wonder if there is a more beautiful way to do this (e.g. indenting the rows below each category).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Description} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{{Category 1}} \\ \midrule
A1 & D1 \\
A2 & D2 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{{Category 2}} \\ \midrule
A3 & D3 \\
A4 & D4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm old-fashioned, but I still  like simple tables:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\toprule
\textbf{Category} & \textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Description} \\ \midrule\\[-.9em]
\multirow{2}{*}{1}
  & A1 & D1 \\
  & A2 & D2 \\[.5em]
\multirow{2}{*}{2}
  & A3 & D3 \\
  & A4 & D4 \\[.5em]
\multirow{2}{*}{3}
  & A2 & D1 \\
  & A3 & D4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise! What I didn't mention was that the description of an attribute might be a little bit longer (however no line break was necessary in my first approach above). If I put the category in one column, I run out of horizontal space.

Comment: Then my choice would be  `\usepackage{tabulary}` in the preamble and start the table with `\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{cLc}` or may be use the sister package `tabularx`  to allow line breaks in the column\s with longs texts.

Answer (score 1):

I will do something like this:

[image: My redesign of the table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\toprule
&\textbf{Attribute} & \textbf{Description} \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small \textsc{category 1}} \\ 
&A1 & D1 \\
&A2 & D2 \\ 
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\small \textsc{category 2}} \\ 
&A3 & D3 \\
&A4 & D4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Key changes:

- Don't use `hline`
- "Indent" the lines using 3 columns instead of 2.
- Distintive typography for "categories."
- Use `@{}` in the column description to remove blank space at the first and last column.